# Synchronizing of shared object which is used by worker threads

Tags: java, multithreading, calendar, synchronization

My last question to this topic and the corresponding answer did not explain all details. So I decide to simplify the code:

```
List<String> wis = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<3000;i++) {
    wis.add("test_" + i);
}   
DayCalc calc = new DayCalc();   
List<List<String>> partition = MyPartition.partition(wis, 30);
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for(List<String> part: partition) {
    Runnable worker = new DayCalcWorker(part, calc);
    executor.execute(worker);
}
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    // Execute all Threads
}
```

The shared class object "calc" is used by all executed threads:

```
public class DayCalc {
    private static int CURRENT_DAY_OF_YEAR = DateTimes.getCurrentCalendarDay();
    ArrayList<String> kwContentArray;

    public DayCalc() {
       kwContentArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    private int getCurrentCalendarDay(Calendar cal) {
       // Reset time to start of day (00:00)
       cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
       cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
       // Get starting day
       Calendar currentTime2 = StartDate.getStartDate();
       System.out.println("Day: " + CURRENT_DAY_OF_YEAR);
       System.out.println("Start Date: " + currentTime2.getTime());
       int day = (int) Convert.daysBetween(currentTime2.getTime(), cal.getTime());
       return day;
    }

    public void setValueFromWorkItem(String wiID, String duration, Calendar cal) {
       if (duration != null) {
        this.setDurationValues(wiID, duration, cal);
       } else {
        int currentDay = getCurrentCalendarDay(cal);
        long time = 0;
        kwContentArray.add(String.valueOf(time));
       }
    }

  // [...]
}
```

Thread Worker class:

```
public class DayCalcWorker implements Runnable {

    private List<String> wis;
    private DayCalc dayCalc;    
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    GregorianCalendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();    

    public DayCalcWorker(List<String> wis, DayCalc dayCalc) {
      this.wis = wis;
      this.dayCalc = dayCalc;
    }    

    @Override
    public void run() {
       if (wis != null && wis.size() > 0) {
           for(String wi: wis) {
             long randomDate = System.currentTimeMillis() + Random.getValue();
             cal.setTime(new Date(randomDate));
             dayCalc.setValueFromWorkItem(wi, "24", cal);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

**Question**

Is it save **not** to synchronize the methods `setValueFromWorkItem` or `getCurrentCalendarDay` because they use e.g. only a **local created calendar object** from each Worker thread?

Because the object `calc` from the class `DayCalc` is shared I have only to keep care of objects which are created within this class and not with passed objects from Worker Threads which are calling methods of `calc`, haven't I?

Note that the code itself makes no sence at all. It just should explain that I use mutable calendar objects which need to synchronized (maybe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not safe. You're modifying a shared list (`kwContentArray`) from inside the `setValueFromWorkItem()` method. So this modification, and all the other accesses to this shared list (read or write), must be synchronized. You coud also use a concurrent List implementation, if that suits your needs.

Comment: Okay, and what is about created GregorianCalendar objects within each thread?

Comment: They're local to each thread, so they don't need to be accessed in a synchronized way.